# how to resize video on click

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

there was a task of such a plan, the site has a video from YouTube, which is included in a small window, how to make it so that when you click on it, it opens 3/4 of the screen, and, accordingly, when it stops, it returns to its original value
example with video block

```html
<div class="flower_petal_video_video">
                                        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/xxx/xxx" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                    </div>
```

```css
.flower_petal_video {
      margin: -60px 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 268px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
              box-shadow: none;
      background-image: url(../img/laptop.png);
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      background-color: #0000;
    }
     
    .flower_petal_video_video {
      /*background-color: #f00;*/
      -webkit-box-flex: 1;
          -ms-flex: 1;
              flex: 1;
      margin: 15.4%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize any HTML element in a specific scale, you can use the transform property to do so.

Using a little bit of JS, it would look like this.

HTML

```
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

JS

```
function resizeDiv() {
  document.getElementById('myDiv').style.transform = 'scale(0.75)';
}
```

This function would scale the div to 3/4 of its original size. The rest is quite simple, find out how the page detects when the video ends, then run a function that resizes it to its original size of `scale(1)`